# Running Sql Analysis server on different server

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-2016

i have server running a database on it, and i have another server which i want to run Analysis server on it, so people can connect the analysis server as they wish to create their own reports for some purposes, but the problem is i could not connect Analysis services to database server which Analysis server can cube the data, according to my research database server and analysis server could be separated, but i could not find any information about how to connect analysis server to database server, the features i install on analysis server are

```
  Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Analysis Services
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed
```

How can i connect Analysis Server to database server which is a different server.
any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried with a linked server?

Comment: the instance i installed as Analysis server does not have that option

Comment: Are you are running in Tabular or dimensional mode? In both cases you need to point your data sources to correct database, but steps are different.

Comment: I am running in Tabular mode, what steps i should take?

Comment: @Piotr if you know something would you share it with me please ?